# How to use charts in Qt?

Tags: qt, charts, widget

I am totally new to Qt. I have installed Qt Creator 3.2.1 based on Qt 5.3.2 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit).I want to use qt charts in qt widget application.I added  "charts" in my application .pro file as Qt documents say. But it says:
 Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: charts.
Is there anything that I am not considering? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update Qt to a newer version, QCharts seems to be shipped with Qt [since version 5.6](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/18/qt-charts-2-1-0-release/).

Before that, it was a module of Qt Entreprise Edition.